# Sitecore 9.1 forced back to log in screen

Tags: identity-server

I have a Sitecore 9.1 instance in a PaaS environment in Azure. On the CM, when I try to log in to Sitecore, I get to the log in screen, I log in successfully, when it tries to redirect me back to Sitecore, it just bounces me right back to the log in screen. I see the Logout link in the top right, so I did get logged in, but I cant get into Sitecore.

Redirect hops after log in look like this:

https://mycmhost/identity/externallogin?authenticationType=SitecoreIdentityServer&ReturnUrl=%2fidentity%2fexternallogincallback%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fsitecore%252fshell%253fsc_lang%253den%26sc_site%3dshell%26authenticationSource%3dDefault&sc_site=shell

gets sent to:

https://myidentityserver/connect/authorize?client_id=etc...

THEN

https://myidentityserver/connect/authorize?client_id=etc...

gets sent to

https://myidentityserver/account/login?client_id=etc...

Not sure whats causing this post log in redirect back to the identity server.

Comment: Looks like the returnURL param is "sitecore/shell" in 
https://mycmhost/identity/externallogin?authenticationType=SitecoreIdentityServer&ReturnUrl=%2fidentity%2fexternallogincallback%3fReturnUrl%3d%252fsitecore%252fshell%253fsc_lang%253den%26sc_site%3dshell%26authenticationSource%3dDefault&sc_site=shell
it supposed to be sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad to properly launch sitecore application.

is your pass instance is plain or any custom code installed? also did you check the admin page  https://sitecore-host/sitecore/admin.

Comment: Sitecore sent me a hotfix:SC-Hotfix-308084-1

Comment: Closing. Problem was hotfixed, mentioned in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue where multiple repeated attempts to log in were redirecting me back to the login page. I had a multi-site solution and was able to simply change domains to log in, but it didn't really solve the issue. Later I was able to solve the issue on my local developer instance using the following url

```
https://{SitecoreDomain}/sitecore/client/Applications/LicenseOptions/KickUser
```

I went to that URL thinking I had too many active sessions and had to remove some of them, but as soon as I hit that URL, instead of asking me to login or showing me a list of active sessions to kill, it took me right into the Sitecore desktop.

Subsequent attempts to log in after hitting this URL were successful. I don't know why it resolved my issue, but it's worth a shot.